# how to display html file from my local folder in tree view

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            var Path = "C:/Users/nshanm/Downloads/tree view/tree view/Reports";
            DirectoryInfo rootInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Path);
            this.PopulateTreeView(rootInfo, null);
        }
    }
    private void PopulateTreeView(DirectoryInfo dirInfo, TreeNode treeNode)
    {
        foreach (DirectoryInfo directory in dirInfo.GetDirectories())
        {
            TreeNode directoryNode = new TreeNode
            {
                Text = directory.Name,
                Value = directory.FullName
            };

            if (treeNode == null)
            {
                //If Root Node, add to TreeView.
                TreeView1.Nodes.Add(directoryNode);
            }
            else
            {
                //If Child Node, add to Parent Node.
                treeNode.ChildNodes.Add(directoryNode);
            }
            //Get all files in the Directory.
            foreach (FileInfo file in directory.GetFiles())
            {
                //Add each file as Child Node.
                TreeNode fileNode = new TreeNode
                {
                    Text = file.Name,
                    Value = file.FullName,
                    Target = "_blank",
                    NavigateUrl = (new Uri(Server.MapPath("~/"))).MakeRelativeUri(new Uri(file.FullName)).ToString()
                };
                directoryNode.ChildNodes.Add(fileNode);
            }

            PopulateTreeView(directory, directoryNode);
        }
     }
```

I am getting folder structure as tree view from my local.but inside a folder i have html file .

I want to display that html file while clicking that file.but i am getting error.can any one help?

My output:

[image]

Comment: which error ? specify error description .

Comment: i am getting 404 error only.

Comment: try  **(new Uri(Server.MapPath("./"))).MakeRelativeUri(new Uri(file.FullName)).ToString()**

Comment: i tried that one .i am getting same error ..i want to navigate that html file while clicking that html..

Comment: whats your porject url and whats your link url (treeview link)?

Comment: [C:/Users/nshanm/Downloads/tree view/tree view/Reports] in this path i have html file.Already  mentioned above folder structure 27-06-2016 ,   28-06-2016 etc.If i click html file that file should display in same page.

Comment: i mean i want link which is display in browser and url .

Comment: C:/Users/nshanm/Downloads/tree view/tree view/Reports This is the url i want to navigate and display the html file dynamically

Comment: i gave this line  NavigateUrl = "~/"+file.Name,it is working. but i copied all html file into my Visual Studio .is it possible without copying all html file into visual studio .